# Regular Expression Matching First Non-Repeated Character

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

**TL;DR**

`re.search("(.)(?!.*\1)", text).group()` doesn't match the first non-repeating character contained in text (it always returns a character at or before the first non-repeated character, or before the end of the string if there are no non-repeated characters. My understanding is that re.search() should return None if there were no matches).
I'm only interested in understanding why this regex is not working as intended using the Python `re` module, not in any other method of solving the problem

**Full Background**

The problem description comes from https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/12/. I've already solved this problem using a non-regex method, but revisited it to expand my understanding of Python's `re` module.
The regular expressions i thought would work (named vs unnamed backreferences) are:

`(?P<letter>.)(?!.*(?P=letter))` and `(.)(?!.*\1)` (same results in python2 and python3)

My entire program looks like this

```
import re
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as test_cases:
    for test in test_cases:
        print(re.search("(?P<letter>.)(?!.*(?P=letter))",
                        test.strip()
                       ).group()
             )
```

and some input/output pairs are:

```
rain | r
teetthing | e
cardiff | c
kangaroo | k
god | g
newtown | e
taxation | x
refurbished | f
substantially | u
```

According to what I've read at https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html:

- `(.)` creates a named group that matches any character and allows later backreferences to it as `\1`.
- `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead which restricts matches to cases where `...` does not match.
- `.*\1` means any number (including zero) of characters followed by whatever was matched by `(.)` earlier
- `re.search(pattern, string)` returns only the first location where the regex pattern produces a match (and would return None if no match could be found)
- `.group()` is equivalent to `.group(0)` which returns the entire match

I think these pieces together should solve the stated problem, and it does work like I think it should for most inputs, but failed on `teething`. Throwing similar problems at it reveals that it seems to ignore repeated characters if they are consecutive:

```
tooth | o      # fails on consecutive repeated characters
aardvark | d   # but does ok if it sees them later
aah | a        # verified last one didn't work just because it was at start
heh | e        # but it works for this one
hehe | h       # What? It thinks h matches (lookahead maybe doesn't find "heh"?)
heho | e       # but it definitely finds "heh" and stops "h" from matching here
hahah | a      # so now it won't match h but will match a
hahxyz | a     # but it realizes there are 2 h characters here...
hahxyza | h    # ... Ok time for StackOverflow
```

I know lookbehind and negative lookbehind are limited to 3-character-max fixed length strings, and cannot contain backreferences even if they evaluate to a fixed length string, but I didn't see the documentation specify any restrictions on negative lookahead.

Comment: This is how you properly ask a regex question. Well done.

Comment: I usually abandon draft questions because I find the answer as I'm documenting my attempts, research, and expectations--or more rarely as I'm fixing formatting after the question is fully written. This one completely eluded my understanding though.

Comment: I find that to often be the case for myself as well. What's less common is someone fairly new to the site asking a regex question with such well documented attempts to solve the problem before coming here. It was refreshing to see.

Comment: Note: current answers don't provide a RegEx only solution for this title: ***Regular Expression Matching First Non-Repeated Character***. They said why and how OP was wrong about his idea behind the solution only. This bounty is started on this question for it to receive a solution to this problem.

Comment: @revo here you go, I added an easy .NET and a Python solution ;) I'm not sure if this is doable with PCRE yet, I need to think about that.

Comment: @revo OK I gave the PCRE solution a thought and came up with the monstrosity you'll see in my answer. It's limited to a predefined alphabet but works. I don't think there's a general-purpose solution to the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well let's take your `tooth` example - here is what the regex-engine does (a lot simplified for better understanding)

Start with `t` then look ahead in the string - and fail the lookahead, as there is another `t`.

```
tooth
^  °
```

Next take `o`, look ahead in the string - and fail, as there is another `o`.

```
tooth
 ^°
```

Next take the second `o`, look ahead in the string - no other `o` present - match it, return it, work done.

```
tooth
  ^
```

So your regex doesn't match the first unrepeated character, but the first one, that has no further repetitions towards the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you. Great example! So, with `re`'s restrictions on negative lookbehind, was I even close, or do you need a totally different approach to do this with regular expressions?

Comment: I don't think you were close (but might be corrected), however I don't really have a regex-solution for this at hand.

Answer (score 15):

[Sebastian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39796953/3764814) already explains pretty well why your current attempt doesn't work.

#### .NET

Since <s>you're</s> [revo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020526/revo) is interested in a .NET flavor workaround, the solution becomes trivial:

```
(?<letter>.)(?!.*?\k<letter>)(?<!\k<letter>.+?)
```

[Demo link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3Cletter%3E.)(%3F!.*%3F%5Ck%3Cletter%3E)(%3F%3C!%5Ck%3Cletter%3E.%2B%3F)&i=tooth%0D%0Aaardvark%0D%0Aaah%0D%0Aheh%0D%0Ahehe%0D%0Aheho%0D%0Ahahah%0D%0Ahahxyz%0D%0Ahahxyza)

This works because .NET supports **variable-length lookbehinds**. You can also get that result with Python (see below).

So for each letter `(?<letter>.)` we check:

- if it's repeated further in the input `(?!.*?\k<letter>)`
- if it was already encountered before `(?<!\k<letter>.+?)`
  (we have to skip the letter we're testing when going backwards, hence the `+`).

---

#### Python

The Python [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) also supports variable-length lookbehinds, so the regex above will work with a small syntactical change: you need to replace `\k` with `\g` (which is quite unfortunate as with this module `\g` is a group backreference, whereas with PCRE it's a recursion).

The regex is:

```
(?<letter>.)(?!.*?\g<letter>)(?<!\g<letter>.+?)
```

And here's an example:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jun  1 2015, 18:05:38)
[GCC 4.9.2] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import regex
>>> regex.search(r'(?<letter>.)(?!.*?\g<letter>)(?<!\g<letter>.+?)', 'tooth')
<regex.Match object; span=(4, 5), match='h'>
```

---

#### PCRE

Ok, now things start to get dirty: since PCRE doesn't support variable-length lookbehinds, we need to *somehow* remember whether a given letter was already encountered in the input or not.

Unfortunately, the regex engine doesn't provide random access memory support. The best we can get in terms of generic memory is a *stack* - but that's not sufficient for this purpose, as a stack only lets us access its topmost element.

If we accept to restrain ourselves to a given alphabet, we can abuse capturing groups for the purpose of storing flags. Let's see this on a limited alphabet of the three letters `abc`:

```
# Anchor the pattern
\A

# For each letter, test to see if it's duplicated in the input string
(?(?=[^a]*+a[^a]*a)(?<da>))
(?(?=[^b]*+b[^b]*b)(?<db>))
(?(?=[^c]*+c[^c]*c)(?<dc>))

# Skip any duplicated letter and throw it away
[a-c]*?\K

# Check if the next letter is a duplicate
(?:
  (?(da)(*FAIL)|a)
| (?(db)(*FAIL)|b)
| (?(dc)(*FAIL)|c)
)
```

Here's how that works:

- First, the `\A` anchor ensures we'll process the input string only once
- Then, for each letter `X` of our alphabet, we'll set up a *is duplicate* flag `dX`:

  - The conditional pattern `(?(cond)then|else)` is used there:

    - The condition is `(?=[^X]*+X[^X]*X)` which is true if the input string contains the letter `X` twice.
    - If the condition is true, the *then* clause is `(?<dX>)`, which is an empty capturing group that will match the empty string.
    - If the condition is false, the `dX` group won't be matched
  - Next, we lazily skip valid letters from our alphabet: `[a-c]*?`
  - And we throw them out in the final match with `\K`
  - Now, we're trying to match *one* letter whose `dX` flag is *not* set. For this purpose, we'll do a conditional branch: `(?(dX)(*FAIL)|X)`

    - If `dX` was matched (meaning that `X` is a duplicated character), we `(*FAIL)`, forcing the engine to backtrack and try a different letter.
    - If `dX` was *not* matched, we try to match `X`. At this point, if this succeeds, we know that `X` is the first non-duplicated letter.

That last part of the pattern could also be replaced with:

```
(?:
  a (*THEN) (?(da)(*FAIL))
| b (*THEN) (?(db)(*FAIL))
| c (*THEN) (?(dc)(*FAIL))
)
```

Which is *somewhat* more optimized. It matches the current letter *first* and only *then* checks if it's a duplicate.

The full pattern for the lowercase letters `a-z` looks like this:

```
# Anchor the pattern
\A

# For each letter, test to see if it's duplicated in the input string
(?(?=[^a]*+a[^a]*a)(?<da>))
(?(?=[^b]*+b[^b]*b)(?<db>))
(?(?=[^c]*+c[^c]*c)(?<dc>))
(?(?=[^d]*+d[^d]*d)(?<dd>))
(?(?=[^e]*+e[^e]*e)(?<de>))
(?(?=[^f]*+f[^f]*f)(?<df>))
(?(?=[^g]*+g[^g]*g)(?<dg>))
(?(?=[^h]*+h[^h]*h)(?<dh>))
(?(?=[^i]*+i[^i]*i)(?<di>))
(?(?=[^j]*+j[^j]*j)(?<dj>))
(?(?=[^k]*+k[^k]*k)(?<dk>))
(?(?=[^l]*+l[^l]*l)(?<dl>))
(?(?=[^m]*+m[^m]*m)(?<dm>))
(?(?=[^n]*+n[^n]*n)(?<dn>))
(?(?=[^o]*+o[^o]*o)(?<do>))
(?(?=[^p]*+p[^p]*p)(?<dp>))
(?(?=[^q]*+q[^q]*q)(?<dq>))
(?(?=[^r]*+r[^r]*r)(?<dr>))
(?(?=[^s]*+s[^s]*s)(?<ds>))
(?(?=[^t]*+t[^t]*t)(?<dt>))
(?(?=[^u]*+u[^u]*u)(?<du>))
(?(?=[^v]*+v[^v]*v)(?<dv>))
(?(?=[^w]*+w[^w]*w)(?<dw>))
(?(?=[^x]*+x[^x]*x)(?<dx>))
(?(?=[^y]*+y[^y]*y)(?<dy>))
(?(?=[^z]*+z[^z]*z)(?<dz>))

# Skip any duplicated letter and throw it away
[a-z]*?\K

# Check if the next letter is a duplicate
(?:
  a (*THEN) (?(da)(*FAIL))
| b (*THEN) (?(db)(*FAIL))
| c (*THEN) (?(dc)(*FAIL))
| d (*THEN) (?(dd)(*FAIL))
| e (*THEN) (?(de)(*FAIL))
| f (*THEN) (?(df)(*FAIL))
| g (*THEN) (?(dg)(*FAIL))
| h (*THEN) (?(dh)(*FAIL))
| i (*THEN) (?(di)(*FAIL))
| j (*THEN) (?(dj)(*FAIL))
| k (*THEN) (?(dk)(*FAIL))
| l (*THEN) (?(dl)(*FAIL))
| m (*THEN) (?(dm)(*FAIL))
| n (*THEN) (?(dn)(*FAIL))
| o (*THEN) (?(do)(*FAIL))
| p (*THEN) (?(dp)(*FAIL))
| q (*THEN) (?(dq)(*FAIL))
| r (*THEN) (?(dr)(*FAIL))
| s (*THEN) (?(ds)(*FAIL))
| t (*THEN) (?(dt)(*FAIL))
| u (*THEN) (?(du)(*FAIL))
| v (*THEN) (?(dv)(*FAIL))
| w (*THEN) (?(dw)(*FAIL))
| x (*THEN) (?(dx)(*FAIL))
| y (*THEN) (?(dy)(*FAIL))
| z (*THEN) (?(dz)(*FAIL))
)
```

And here's the [demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Mhwxog/1), complete with unit tests.

You can expand on this pattern if you need a larger alphabet, but obviously this is *not* a general-purpose solution. It's primarily of educational interest and should *not* be used for any serious application.

---

For other flavors, you may try to tweak the pattern to replace PCRE features with simpler equivalents:

- `\A` becomes `^`
- `X (*THEN) (?(dX)(*FAIL))` can be replaced with `(?(dX)(?!)|X)`
- You may throw away the `\K` and replace the last noncapturnig group `(?:`...`)` with a named group like `(?<letter>`...`)` and treat its content as the result.

The only required but somewhat unusual construct is the conditional group `(?(cond)then|else)`.

Comment: This truly answers this question (being a. NET solution) but I had to specify and mention *without using variable-length feature of lookbehinds* since OP and other answers had talked about this and by knowing this a bounty couldn't be started. Excuse me. My bad.

Comment: That's a neat workaround and I mostly liked this part `[a-z]*?\K`. However it is not a general solution as you too pointed out. +1. You may take the bounty at the end.

Answer (score 5):

Regular expressions are not optimal for the task even if you use alternative implementations of re that do not limit lookbehind by fixed length strings (such as Matthew Barnett's regex).

The easiest way is to count occurrences of letters and print the first one with frequency equal to 1:

```
import sys
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

# Counter that remembers that remembers the order entries were added
class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass

# Calling next() once only gives the first entry
first=next

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as test_cases:
    for test in test_cases:
        lettfreq = OrderedCounter(test)
        print(first((l for l in lettfreq if lettfreq[l] == 1)))
```

Comment: Gave a +1 for referencing Matthew Barnett's `regex`. Although I explicitly stated that I wasn't interested in other regex modules, the `regex` module that is intended to eventually replace `re` in the standard library is a worthwhile exception. The rest of the answer isn't too helpful to me since I had already solved the problem in a similar way without regex's, but still might be helpful to another user. Clear code with a concise explanation that adds a lot that wasn't covered by the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your regex is not working is that it will not match a character that is *followed* by the same character, but there is nothing to prevent it from matching a character that isn't *followed* by the same character, *even if* it is preceded by the same character.

Comment: Thank you. The italics really helped me hone in on the distinction. So, with `re`'s restrictions on negative lookbehind, was I even close, or do you need a totally different approach to do this with regular expressions? Sebastian got it 1 minute before you, but I would have accepted your answer had timing been different. Concise, but fully answered the question.

Comment: I'm not a regex guru, but I'm sure you could hack a way to do this. However, a non-regex solution would be trivial and more readable.

Comment: And probably have better performance too. Variable length lookaheads and (effectively if I could hack it) lookbehinds can't be good for performance. My non-regex solution to the problem was max 2 passes over the string to 1.) count occurrences of each character, storing sums in a dictionary 2.) print the first character whose count was 1. This attempt did help me learn something though. Thanks again!